# Sequentially color paragraphs in LaTeX document

Tags: color, paragraphs

This question is similar to [Randomly color paragraphs in LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157014/randomly-color-paragraphs-in-latex-document) , but I want to color the paragraphs with unique color (color list), is there any way to do this? (I want to comment on the original question's answer, but I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153281/11604 but change of color is very subtle line by line (the idea here was that the color changes  wouldn't be noticed easily).

Answer (score 5):

There sure is room for improvement (e.g. one could define the color list as a comma-separated list), but you can use the following code, shamelessly based on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157158/82917) to the question you linked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook,xcolor,lipsum}

\newcounter{cyclecolor}
\newcommand*{\cyclecolor}{%
  \stepcounter{cyclecolor}%
  \ifcase\value{cyclecolor}%
  \or\color{red}%
  \or\color{orange}%
  \or\color{teal}%
  % add further colors here
  \or\color{blue}%
     \setcounter{cyclecolor}{0}% the last one in the list must reset the counter
  \fi}

\PushPostHook{par}{\cyclecolor} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157158/82917

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can define two user macros`\cyclecolor` and `\nocyclecolor` which switch the behaviour mid-document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook,xcolor,lipsum}

\newcounter{cyclecolor}

\makeatletter
\def\@cyclecolor{\relax}
\newcommand*{\cyclecolor}{\def\@cyclecolor{\@@cyclecolor}}
\newcommand*{\nocyclecolor}{\color{black}\def\@cyclecolor{\relax}}

\newcommand*{\@@cyclecolor}{%
  \stepcounter{cyclecolor}%
  \ifcase\value{cyclecolor}%
  \or\color{red}%
  \or\color{orange}%
  \or\color{teal}%
  % add further colors here
  \or\color{blue}%
     \setcounter{cyclecolor}{0}%
  \fi}

\PushPostHook{par}{\@cyclecolor}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
% start with normal black
\lipsum[66]

\cyclecolor % cycles through colors
\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[75]

\nocyclecolor % restores normal black
\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured out to apply color with the help of counter also. Can I change the background color of each paragraphs in this way? (Keep the text and background the same color, so as to segment different paragraphs.) Actually, my original target is to located different text by bounding box which seems hard (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519455/is-there-any-ways-to-show-the-bounding-boxes-of-a-tex-text), so I changed to this colored way. If you know any other way, that will be more appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not fully tested but ...

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolorseries{parrafo}{rgb}{last}{blue}{red}
\resetcolorseries[3]{parrafo}
\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{\oldpar\color{parrafo!!+}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
\lipsum[2][1-5]\par
\lipsum[3][1-5]\par
\lipsum[4][1-5]\par
\lipsum[3][1-5]\par
\lipsum[4][1-5]\par
\section{More test}
\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
\lipsum[2][1-5]\par
\lipsum[3][1-5]\par
\lipsum[4][1-5]\par
\lipsum[3][1-5]\par
\lipsum[4][1-5]\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you help on this: How can I replace the several start-ing and end-ing characters of each paragraph? [What I really want is to locate each text line in final pdf, but couldn't find the direct way. So tried so many other ways but not success 

Comment: The begin and end of paragraphs are always enough clear except when both  `\parskip` and `\parindent` are not nearly ` 0pt`,  and this is inusual (and wrong), so it is not still clear for me what you really need. Make a new question, describing not the problem to solve the solutions that you are thinking (highlight with color, replace characters  or whatever) but your true problem as clearly as possible. That  mean  using a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  where you can explaining what is problematic exactly.

Comment: Usually the macro used as a fallback of `\par` is `\endgraf`, no need to do a `\let\oldpar\par`.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I have clarified what I really ned in the new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519906/translate-english-tex-to-chinese-precisely