# Translate English TeX to Chinese precisely

Tags: extract, translate

This is essentially the question of how to locate changeable text content in the TeX file. Does LaTeX have certain rule to separate the commands and text? By the way, can these text be classified into different types like title/paragraph/footer/header/reference/caption/equation?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. I think it is safe to say that TeX does not have a rule to separate commands and text, although usually commands start with a backslash, like \section to start a section. I don't understand your reference to English and Chinese, or how that relates to changeable text.

Comment: What I want to do is to change all the english content to Chinese content, but keep the same structure.

Comment: Thanks, I see now what you mean. I don't see how to solve the problem, but I understand what the problem is.

Comment: This might be the first step in your process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530121/how-do-i-convert-latex-to-plain-text-ascii